# PHP Binary Image Data

Tags: php, image, binary

I'm working with some binary image data given to me by another developer and trying to figure out how to display the images on the screen. The binary images all look like this:

0xFFD8FFE000104A46494...[TRUNCATED]...F6145145690D8E4ACFDE3FFFD9

I've tried the following PHP code to get the image to save:

```
$data = '0xFFD8FFE000104A46494...F6145145690D8E4ACFDE3FFFD9'; //full data entered here
$string = pack('H*', $data);
$result = imagecreatefromstring($string);
imagejpeg($result, 'test.jpg');
```

This saves an image called test.jpg, but it is a jumbled image and not the actual image it should be.

I also tried using base64 like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($data) ?>">
```

which also did not work. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Binary data could be anything, do you know how it's created?

Comment: Your best bet is to talk to the developer or otherwise you could be fiddling with this for ages

Comment: Unless you suddenly become a compiler you should talk to the developer by pretending to know how it's created :D

Comment: Its not base64.  FFD8 is correct for a jpeg.  Try `file_put_contents("test.jpg", pack('H*', $data));`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will attempt to find out how it was created. It got the same result using your code also Alex. I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: Remove the '0x' at the beginning before the packing